# C#: convert Unicode to use as url

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm working on multilingual Asp.NET MVC application. In url i need to use category name.
Is there any way how to convert i.e japanese text to its url safe equivalent?
Or should i use original text in url(www.example.com/製品/車 = www.example.com/product/car)?

EDIT:
I need SEO firenly urls. I know how to strip diacritics and replace spaces(or other special characters) with '-'. But i wonder how to deal with foreign languages like Japanese, Russian etc.

Comment: I doubt there is a generic way to convert any language of this planet to US-ASCII and get meaningful results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) the path elements, but the result will be  illegible for the human eye (and probably search engines as well). Translating the elements to English or romanizing them sounds like a good idea. You need a dictionary though:

```
var comparer = StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("ja-JP"), false);

var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(comparer)
{
    { "",     ""        },
    { "製品", "product" },
    { "車",   "car"     },
};

var path = "/製品/車";

var translatedPath = string.Join("/", path.Split('/').Select(s => dict[s]));
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you are generating the url but you could use the [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) method.

Comment: IMHO, result from UrlEncode is not SEO friendly. Server.UrlEncode("á") returns "%c3%a1".

Answer (score 1):

If you think a crawler could guess the product names or categories correctly to land on all pages of your site, it would be just as likely to do so with a number.  Use the name or category ID, saves you the hassle from localizing these names as well.